# Linux live won't connect to internet

Tags: internet, live-usb, ethernet

I want to install Ubuntu in my office desktop so I made a live USB so that the installed OS in the office won't be messed up. The problem is that it won't connect to the internet (wired connection, no wifi card), I have already tried both Elementary OS and Ubuntu in both persistent and non persistent modes but none worked.

I don't really know what the hardware is, all I know is that it's a ThinkPad and has Windows 7 64-bit running on it.

Also another thing I noticed is that if I plug in work's ethernet to my laptop it won't connect to internet (neither Elementary OS nor Windows) just will connect. Does anyone know if they can be just used on specific computers?

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. Do you mean it connects to the local network but not the internet? Also, you mention a "desktop" but then say your machine is a thinkpad which is a laptop. Which is it? Please [edit] and clarify. Also add i) the output of running `lspci -nn | grep etw`; ii) the output of running `dmesg | tail -n 20` right after connecting the network cable and iii) the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: Im sorry, it is a thinkcentre, got confused, its my corporate's desktop so i think below's answer is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "Office desktop" you probably mean "corporate computer" and the corporation you work for will have all kinds of protections in place that will actively block "visitors" to the corporation from just surfing the Internet. (like proxy servers, certificates, authentication, ...)

By booting your corporate computer with an Ubuntu image, you've just turned it into a "Visitor's computer", so you should talk to your IT department on how to obtain Internet access for visitors and apply that procedure to your Ubuntu install.

Comment: Yeah, i think thats the problem, it is a corporate computer, is there any workaround for this or the only solution is to talk to the IT? Thxs

Comment: If they were half as smart as I was back when I was still IT: Yes!  **;-)**  If not: it all depends on their architecture and with enough patience you might get through, but if you're working for a big multinational, I'm giving you as much chance as a snowflake in hell, so go talk to the guys and tell them why you need Ubuntu and they might just *give* you access.

Comment: Also, if this answer helped, [don't forget to accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @MarioQuintero: Favour returned, Q upvoted!